# How to span header with column in flextable or gtsummary

Tags: r, gtsummary, flextable

How can I get this

```
library(dplyr)
library(flextable)  
  mtcars %>% 
    select(mpg, cyl, am) %>% 
    group_by(cyl, am) %>% 
    summarise(mean_mpg = mean(mpg),
              sd_mpg = sd(mpg)) %>% 
    flextable()
```

[image]

**To this:**

[image]

Comment: The gt package has a `gt::tab_spanner()` function for this.

Comment: @Daniel D. Sjoberg. Thank you very much. I tried with gtsummary because I wanted to make statistics showing the p value. But I was not possible for me : `mtcars %>% 
  select(mpg, cyl, am) %>% 
  tbl_summary(
    by=am,
    type = list(mpg ~ 'continuous2'),
    statistic = all_continuous() ~ c("{N_nonmiss}",
                                     "{mean} ({sd})", 
                                     "{median} ({p25}, {p75})", 
                                     "{min}, {max}"),
    missing = "no"
  ) %>%
  italicize_levels() %>% 
  as_flex_table()`. could you please help.

Comment: I wanted to show mpg N, Mean, Median, Range for each cyl. E.g. 3 times.

Comment: Like this? `mtcars %>%
  select(mpg, cyl, am) %>%
  tbl_summary(
    by = am, 
    type = list(mpg ~ "continuous2"), 
    statistic = all_continuous() ~ c("{N_nonmiss}", "{mean} ({sd})", "{median} ({p25}, {p75})", "{min}, {max}"), 
    missing = "no"
  ) %>%
  italicize_levels() %>%
  modify_spanning_header(all_stat_cols() ~ "**Transmission Type**")`

Comment: Not exactly. Anyway I thank you very much for your time. I think I have to grab my brain a little more to exactly name what I want. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need `tidyr::pivot_wider()` and `ftExtra::span_header()`. If you wish to make the empty spaces between column use "empty" col_keys in `flextable`.

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(flextable)  

mtcars %>% 
  select(mpg, cyl, am) %>% 
  group_by(cyl, am) %>% 
  summarise(mean_mpg = mean(mpg),
            sd_mpg = sd(mpg)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = am, values_from = c(mean_mpg, sd_mpg), names_glue = "am {am}.{.value}", names_vary = "slowest") %>% 
  flextable(col_keys = c(names(.)[1],"blank1",names(.)[2:3], "blank2", names(.)[4:5] )) |> 
  ftExtra::span_header(sep = "\\.") |> 
  empty_blanks()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Could we centralize am 0 and am 1?

Comment: after `span_header` use `align(i = 1, align = 'center' ,part = "header")`

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `tabulator()`+`as_flextable()` functions:

```
library(dplyr)
library(flextable)  
mtcars %>% 
  select(mpg, cyl, am) %>% 
  group_by(cyl, am) %>% 
  summarise(mean_mpg = mean(mpg),
            sd_mpg = sd(mpg)) %>% 
  tabulator(rows = "cyl", columns = "am",
            `μ` = as_paragraph(mean_mpg), 
            `σ` = as_paragraph(sd_mpg)) |> 
  as_flextable()
```

[image]

Comment: This is a very good answer. I keep M Aurélio s answer as accepted.

Comment: no problem, I just wanted to show this solution :)